Trouble Reimaging Ubuntu on MSI Cyborg Laptop
I need help reimaging Ubuntu on my MSI Cyborg laptop. I'm aiming for Ubuntu 20.04, but I'm encountering issues. It seems like the root file system is undefined. When I attempt to mount the partitions (dev, boot, etc.), the system freezes and prevents me from doing anything. Additionally, everything appears magnified, and I'm unable to change the display settings.
Interestingly, Ubuntu 22 installs without any issues. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. If you need the laptop's specifications, please let me know.
enter image description here

Curious question: if 22.04 installs fine, but 20.04 doesn't, why don't you go for 22.04? (This may be a driver issue, because 22.04 is more advanced)
